# grails error message in an independent gsp view

Tags: grails, search, message

In my grails project I've built up a new view in which user can perform a search of entities. 
I've created the gsp adding the method search() in controller and automatically creating the gsp as described [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-grails-views-and-actions.html)
In this gsp there is only one input field and a g:actionSubmit button. If I fill form with correct data everything works well, but if data does not have any correspondance I would see an error message in the view like the validation error messages with popups...but I don't know how to show it, because I'm not using any bean with this gsp.
In addition, after an error, I would render the same view, but with `render(view: "search", model: [patientInstance: patientInstance])` the view is the same, but path is /index and not /search...

How can I show an error message? How can I have the right path?

here is the search()

```
def search()
{

    def patientInstance = new Patient()


    if(params.patient_textField == "" || params.patient_textField == " " || params.patient_id =="")
    {

        //here I would like to show message

        //the redirect works correctly
         redirect(controller: "patient", action: "search")
    }

    else {

        def patientToShow = Patient.findById(params.patient_id)
        redirect(controller: "patient", action: "show", params: [id: patientToShow?.id])
    }

}
```

here is the snippet of gsp

```
 <g:form>
<div id="patientDiv">
    <label for="patient">
        <g:message code="event.patient.label" default="Patient" />

    </label>

        <input style=" margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;" type="text" name="patient_textField" id="patient_textField" value="" placeholder="${g.message(code: 'patient.choose', default: 'Insert Patient...')}" />
        <input type="hidden" id="patient_id" name="patient_id" value="" />        

    <g:actionSubmit class="search" value="${g.message(code: 'default.search.label', default: 'Search Patient')}" action="search" ></g:actionSubmit>
</div>
</g:form>
```

EDIT:
solved problem of path changing render with  `redirect(controller: "patient", action: "search")`

Comment: http://grails.org/doc/2.0.0/ref/Tags/renderErrors.html

Comment: I've read the article but which bean do I need to use for renderErrors?

Answer (score 1):

In the error portion of your code you can do flash.error = "Your error message here"
And in the gsp do something like:

```
<g:if test="${flash.error}">
    <div class="alert alert-info">
      ${flash.message}
    </div>
  </g:if>
```

There is already a flash bean in scope.  http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/flash.html

Comment: It works, but I would have an error like the one seen in validation, for example when input field become red and popup message is shown...